# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'dev' (webpack-dev-server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I installed webpack-dev-server, there are no errors when building a project, the server successfully starts, but in the browser console it knocks out such an error 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module' dev 'when trying to load index.html, the server returns main.js file I can not understand what the problem is, please help!

```
webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: './main',
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
        { test: /\.js$/, loader: "babel-loader" }
      ]
    },
    watch:true
  };

package.json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "gsap": "^2.1.3",
    "howler": "^2.1.2",
    "pixi.js": "^5.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.34.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.1"
  }
}

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
<body>
</body>
<script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
</html>

main.js

let PIXI = require('pixi.js');
let HOWLER = require('howler');
import TimeLineMax from 'gsap/TimelineMax';

const log = console.warn;
let doc = document;

//Aliases
let Application = PIXI.Application,
  loader = PIXI.Loader.shared,
  resources = PIXI.Loader.resources,
  Sprite = PIXI.Sprite,
  Container = PIXI.Container,
  Howl = HOWLER.Howl, 
  Graphics =  PIXI.Graphics;

//constants
const WIDTHCARDPLACE = 200;
const HEIGHTCARDPLACE = 300;

let app = new Application({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  antialias: true
});

app.renderer.backgroundColor = 0xFFFFFF;

app.renderer.view.style.position = "absolute";
app.renderer.view.style.display = "block";
app.renderer.autoResize = true;
app.renderer.resize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

doc.body.appendChild(app.view);
setup.sprites = {};

const bottomPanel = new Container();

loader
.add("images/background.jpg", (resource) => {
  const background = new Sprite(resource.texture);
  app.stage.addChild(background);
})
  .add("images/button_nachat.png", (resource) => {

    const beginBtn = new Sprite(resource.texture);

    beginBtn.position.set(0, 0);
    beginBtn.buttonMode = true;
    beginBtn.interactive = true;

        //handler on the button start 
        beginBtn.on('pointerdown', function (e) {

        });

    bottomPanel.addChild(beginBtn);

  }).load(setup);

//all downloads are complete
function setup() {

  //add sprites to stage
/*   for (const key in setup.sprites) {
    app.stage.addChild(setup.sprites[key]);
  }*/

const countCards = 5;
let vxCardPlace = 0;

const containerCardPlace = new Container();

for (let i = countCards; i--;){
  let cardPlace = new Graphics();
  cardPlace.beginFill(0x000000);
  cardPlace.drawRect(vxCardPlace, 0, WIDTHCARDPLACE, HEIGHTCARDPLACE);
  vxCardPlace += 250;
  cardPlace.endFill();
  containerCardPlace.addChild(cardPlace);
}

bottomPanel.position
.set(app.view.width / 2 - bottomPanel.width / 2, app.view.height - bottomPanel.height - 5);

containerCardPlace.position
.set(app.view.width / 2 - containerCardPlace.width / 2, window.innerHeight / 2 - bottomPanel.height);


app.stage.addChild(containerCardPlace);
app.stage.addChild(bottomPanel);


let tl = new TimeLineMax();
let obj = {a:0};
let line = new Graphics();
line.lineStyle(4, 0xFFFFFF, 1);
app.stage.addChild(line);

//animation experiment
tl.to(obj, 0.8, {a:1, onUpdate: function(){

  line.moveTo(0, 0);
  line.lineTo(app.view.width, 0);
  line.lineTo(app.view.width, Math.sqrt(app.view.height * obj.a));
  line.lineTo(0, app.view.height * obj.a);

}});

getRandomCards(1, containerCardPlace);
}


function randomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

//selects a random card
function getRandomCards (count, containerCards) {
const cardsArray = [];

for (let i = count; i--;){
  let card = new Graphics();
  card.beginFill(0x66CCFF);
  card.lineStyle(4, 0xFF3300, 1);
  card.drawRect
  (containerCards.children[0].position.x, containerCards.children[0].position.y, WIDTHCARDPLACE - 4, HEIGHTCARDPLACE - 4);
  card.endFill();
  containerCards.addChild(card);
}
}
```

[image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB0Of.png)

Comment: you need to show your code

Comment: Before using webpack-dev-server, I collected a project just webpack, and everything worked.

Comment: The problem is not in the code